# keyboard layout is flickering while entering OTP (only on android)?

Tags: next.js

While entering OTP on android devices , the keyboard layout kind of flashes. the same happens while deleting the OTP.

```
    import { useState } from "react";
    import OtpInput from "react-otp-input";
    
    const otp = () => {
      const [OTP, setOTP] = useState("");
    
      const handleChange = (e) => {
        setOTP(e);
      };
      return (
        <div className="flex justify-center items-center h-screen">
          <OtpInput
            value={OTP}
            onChange={handleChange}
            numInputs={6}
            separator={<span className="p-1">-</span>}
            isInputNum={true}
            shouldAutoFocus={true}
            inputStyle={{
              border: "1px solid gray",
              borderRadius: "8px",
              width: "54px",
              height: "54px",
              fontSize: "20px",
              color: "#000",
              fontWeight: "400",
              caretColor: "blue",
            }}
            // focusStyle={{
            //   border: "1px solid black",
            //   outline: "none",
            // }}
          />
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default otp;
```

please help me to fix this problem.

Comment: Is this a ReactJS app loaded in the browser? Or are you actually working in React Native? Either way, we'd need to see some code and significantly more info to even have a chance at solving this.

Comment: Please add relevant code

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.